# HTTP Redirect (302) Doesn't Use Cookie in Following GET Request

Tags: http, redirect, cookies, get, setcookie

Here is a question I have been researching for some time now.

I have a redirect that does not seem to be respecting a Set-Cookie attribute in a 302 Redirect.

Here are the request and response headers that I used wireshark to obtain.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Location: http://192.168.1.1:8888/home/\r\n
Set-Cookie: foo=test_data; Domain=192.168.1.1; Path=/\r\n
\r\n

GET /home/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 192.168.1.1:8888\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36\r\n
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n
DNT: 1\r\n
\r\n
```

I sanitized the content just a bit, but nothing critical should have been modified.  The point is no matter the browser I use, the cookie 'foo' is not put in the GET request following the 302. From what I have read, this is not expected behavior. Am I incorrect in believing this?  Is there something that I am missing or doing wrong with the 302?

Comment: When you access URL that returns `302`, is it hosted on `192.168.1.1:8888`?

Comment: No, it can be anything. The redirect is formed essentially as a MITM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the question, `Cookie` header does not appear in the redirected HTTP request (`GET http://192.168.1.1:8888/home`). The root cause is: the cookie `foo=test_data` never exists. When it is delivered from server by `Set-Cookie` response header, it would be rejected by browser, as its `Domain` does not include the original server.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie):

> A cookie belonging to a domain that does not include the origin server **should be rejected by the user agent.** The following cookie will be rejected if it was set by a server hosted on originalcompany.com.
>
> Set-Cookie: qwerty=219ffwef9w0f; Domain=somecompany.co.uk; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 30 Aug 2019 00:00:00 GMT

For more accurate description, you can check [RFC6265 section -4.1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3)

This is designed with a good reason. If all server can `Set-Cookie` for all domain, it would be extremely easy to wipe out other website's cookie, which would be a disaster for internet.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I have read that page several times and never noticed that crucial detail.  Even then, this makes it easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: as it pertains to this question, crucially it's because the domain in the set-cookie has no port number, and the domain in the Location has port 8888 this makes them effectively different domains.